# error smtp ruby on rails error en excepcion y en consola

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Tengo 2 tokens uno para exceder a los métodos de api y otro para hacer un password reset y que se forme una url que se envia por correo para hacer el password reset

el problema es que al acceder al api y hacer un post a password_reset con el correo manda el error de la excepción `{ "error": "Fail save user with temporal password recovery token" }`

subi my proyecto Git Hub https://github.com/eminem1542/api-juego-selva

el problema es que al hacer post a reset password con email desde Postman no se envia el correo ya configure mi gmail para conectarse a app poco seguras y el captcha de google igual y me manda al error de la excepción en el controlador de usuario la función

y en consola manda este error

```
 Started POST "/users/password_reset" for ::1 at 2019-07-24 12:28:28 -0500
Processing by UsersController#password_reset as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"conejo1542@gmail.com", "user"=>{"email"=>"conejo1542@gmail.com"}}
HTTP Origin header (chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) didn't match request.base_url (http://localhost:3000)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "conejo1542@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

user_controller.rb

```
  def password_reset  
    user_email = params['email']
    @user = User.find_by(email: user_email)
    if @user
      password_recovery_token = SecureRandom.hex(32)
      @user.password_recovery_token = password_recovery_token
      @user.password_recovery_expiration = Time.now
      begin
        @user.update
        base_url = request.protocol + request.host_with_port

        ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user, base_url).deliver

        render json: {success: 'request reset password successful'}, status: :ok 
      rescue Exception => e
        render json: {error: 'Fail save user with temporal password recovery token'}, status: :internal_server_error
      end
    else
      render json: {error: 'User not found'}, status: :not_found
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede que esto no sea una solución del todo, pero puede darte pistas para resolver tu problema. En este momento veo que tu principal falla está en estas líneas:

```
  rescue Exception => e
    render json: {error: 'Fail save user with temporal password recovery token'}, status: :internal_server_error
```

- [Revisa aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby) por qué no es buena idea usar `rescue Exception`. En términos generales siempre es mejor capturar la excepción específica que esperas.
- Estás rescatando la excepción y luego entregando al cliente un mensaje `Fail save user with temporal password recovery token` con un `500` como  status de respuesta, lo cual creo que no tiene ningún sentido, ya que no es información útil para el cliente. En general, si desde el lado del servidor se entrega un estado 5xx ([error de servidor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Errores_de_servidor)), **debe ser el cliente** quien debe saber **que hacer** con aquello. En otras palabras, si el cliente recibe un error del servidor, en este caso un 500, debe ser quien muestre en pantalla un mensaje `Fail save user with...` o lo que sea.
- Lo último y más importante, **estas silenciando el error**, porque capturas cualquier error que recibas y retornas un mensaje que no le entrega ninguna utilidad ni al cliente ni a ti como desarrollador, ya que no sabes cual error específico sucedió.

Lo que yo haría en tu lugar sería:

- sacar `begin-rescue` y dejar que la aplicación falle cuando tenga que fallar. Por X razón puede suceder un error del servidor fuera de este bloque (ejemplo, tu servidor de DB puede estar caído y fallará en `User.find_by(email: user_email)`) y el cliente de todas formas va a recibir un 500 como respuesta sin ningún mensaje extra. Él tiene que saber qué hacer con un 500, no decirle el servidor qué hacer.
- agregar un `if-else` a tu `@user.update` y, en caso que no haya podido actualizar, retornar un json de error con un estado 4xx ([error de cliente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Errores_de_cliente)), donde aquí sí puedes mandarle un mensaje de error, para que sepa cuál fue su error o que información esperaba el servidor que el cliente le mandara. En otras palabras, lo que hace un controlador rails de toda la vida.
- Ejecutar `ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user, base_url).deliver` [asíncronamente](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#action-mailer) por dos razones. Una, porque se conecta a un servidor SMTP externo, puede haber lentitud en la red, el servidor puede estar saturado, caído, mil cosas que al final del día se traducen en demora en la respuesta de tu servidor al cliente. Otra, porque es susceptible a errores. Al parecer es en ésta línea donde se está causando tu error, sin embargo el cliente no tendría por qué enterarse de que tienes un problema con el servidor de correo, ya que es algo secundario al reset de contraseña.

Si no logras dilucidar cual es tu problema de conexión al servidor SMTP, te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta con el código específico involucrado, configuración, error completo arrojado, etc.